# Submartingales bounded in $L^p$, $p>1$

Tags: pr.probability, limits-and-convergence, martingales

Let $p>1$ be a real number.  It is known that if $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$  is a martingale bounded in $L^p$ (i.e. $\sup\{\mathbb{E}(|X_n|^p), n\geq 0\} < +\infty$ ), then $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ converges a.s. and in $L^p$ to $X\in L^p$. This results is still true if $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a positive submartingale.
However, do we have such convergence results if we only suppose that $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a submartingale? 
Most of books only consider the case where $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ is a martingale.

Comment: You get a.s. convergence just from $L^1$ boundedness (positivity not needed), and then from Vitali you get $L^q$ convergence for every $q < p$.  Can you give a reference for the statement that for a martingale, you actually get $L^p$ convergence?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The $L^p$ convergence is a consequence of the dominated convergence theorem and the Doob Inequality. There is a proof (in french) here, p.37 [link](http://www.proba.jussieu.fr/pageperso/levy/4M011_Poly.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The almost sure convergence is true for any submartingale with an integrable upper  majorant. This implies the $L^1$ convergence through uniform integrability.

However, in general, there is no convergence in $L^p$. I'll give a counterexample for $p=2$, but it can be modified for any $p>1$.

Let $X_n = - e^{W_n - n}$, where $W$ is the standard Wiener process. This is a submartingale with $E[X^2_n] = 1$, and $X_n\to 0$, $n\to\infty$, almost surely. But there is no convergence in $L^2$.

Answer (score 0):

A stronger condition that does guarantee $L^p$ convergence for submartingales is as follows:

1. $\sup_k \{E|M_k|^p + E|A_k|^p\} < \infty.$
   where $X_k = M_k + A_k$ is Doob's decomposition.

For a proof, see my answer to this question:  [$L^p$-convergence of submartingale](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397788/lp-convergence-of-submartingale/397833#397833)

This clearly implies $\sup_k E|X_k|^p < \infty$.